# encrypt on server decrypt on client

Tags: encryption

I'm building a simple trivia game that has "hangman" style clues (where letters are revealed as the player asks for hints).  I don't want to flat out send the answer with the question any user with sufficient smarts could figure it out) - rather I'd like to encrypt answers on the server and decrypt them on the client.  Security isn't of huge importance I just want to make the process harder then it's worth for players.  I was wondering if anyone could recommend a strategy for doing this?

Comment: You could try using SSL sockets to send data. It's relativly simple to implement with the OpenSSL library for C/C++ http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl/index.html should get you started. If you are worried about the user using a memory editor, you are out of luck. The best you can do is encrypt the network stream from packet sniffers.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach, which might be sufficiently difficult for most users, would be to send the answer and encryption key to the web client (as hidden form fields), and use Javascript to decrypt it on the fly (inside the browser). A simple exclusive-or'ing of the answer string characters with the key string should be sufficient to "shroud" the answer without requiring large amounts of crypto processing on the client side. Using more than one key string might increase the difficulty of cracking it, too.

I'm assuming that you don't want to implement full commercial-grade crypto on the client side, and also assuming that you only want to hide the answers for a few minutes at most.